# GET parameters cant retrieve using php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

I'm working on a php page which can't retrieve the GET parameter values from the browser url

ex- if i pass below url via browser

```
http://www.test.com/afvalbakken?price[]=&price[]=&17[]=&17[]=&16[]=107&18[]=180
```

the var_dump($_GET) the output below array.and it not shows the parameters passed

```
array(1) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(11) "afvalbakken"
}
```

i use a htaccess file for some url rewrite.below has its codes

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

anyone know how to access those get parameters please, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `QSA` flag here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag **preserves existing query parameters** when you are adding a new one.

Comment: great this seems working fine, will this effect for current url rewrite system of the website, thanks

Comment: No it won't affect any rewrite.